# Why doesn't my vue app start after running `npm run serve`?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I'm having a bad time here. For the past 24 hours I suppose.
I recently started learning Javascript and I choose Vue JS as the JS framework of choice.

My vue js app throws me a plethora of errors without meaning constantly when `npm run serve` is ran.
After a while or after tweaking a lot of things like `npm init` then `npm install`(I usually don't understand what I do), `npm run serve` starts the app successfully.
[after running `npm run serve`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0KFN.png)

How can I go over this? And what is actually going on here that I don't understand.
I'd need explanations too. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The solution worked.
I also need an explanation for this problem. And what does that command do specifically? Thanks

Comment: You can get a lot of explanations by just googling the error - `ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached`

Comment: Ref *"errors without meaning"*, `System limit for number of file watchers reached` is quite meaningful. As a programmer, get used to running into lots of errors with a lot less *English* meaning than this one.

Comment: I will Tao!. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux there is a limit on file watcher. You just need to increase that limit:
To do this: open the file **/etc/sysctl.conf** and set **fs.inotify.max_user_watches** option to **524288** . Like this: **fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288**